# Create slick slider by using javascript not jquery

Tags: slick.js

Is there any way how to use slick slider by using pure javascript, not jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

None that I know of.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/494) to an GitHub issue with your question.

In there you can find that kenwheeler (owner of slick) says that there is o reason for that.